# Свой шаблонизатор на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, пишу свой шаблонизатор php, в данный момент выглядит он вот так:

```
class Template {

    private $dir_tmpl; // Директория с tpl-файлами
    private $data = array(); // Данные для вывода

    public function __construct($dir_tmpl) {
        $this->dir_tmpl = $dir_tmpl;
    }

    /* Метод для добавления новых значений в данные для вывода */
    public function set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    /* Метод для удаления значений из данных для вывода */
    public function delete($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    /* При обращении, например, к $this->title будет выводиться $this->data["title"] */
    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) return $this->data[$name];
        return "";
    }

    /* Вывод tpl-файла, в который подставляются все данные для вывода */
    public function display($template) {
        if($template == "header" || $template == "body" || $template == "footer"){
            $template = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template/main_tpl/".$template.".tpl";
        }else{
            $template = $this->dir_tmpl.$template.".tpl";
        }

        ob_start();
        include ($template);

        echo ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function render() {

    }
}
```

В данный момент суть такова:

Cоздаю новый шаблон:
$template = new Template($root_dir."template/manager/");

Я создаю массив с переменными:

```
$menu = array(
        "/manager" => array("title" => "Главная", "class" => "active"),
        "/" => array("title" => "Сайт", "class" => ""),
        "exit" => array("title" => "Выход", "class" => ""),
);

$template->set("menu", $menu);
```

Шаблон выглядит так

```
<header id="header">
    <img class="logo" src="/template/manager/images/logo.png">
    <nav>
        <? foreach ($this->menu AS $href => $data){ ?>
        <a href="<?=$href?>" class="<?= $data['class']?>"><?=$data['title']?></a>
        <? } ?>
    </nav>
</header>
```

и вывожу на страницу

```
$template->display("menu");
```

Данный Class не позволяет вставлять один шаблон в другой.

Мне необходимо создавать переменную с шаблонам а потом как и обычно вставить её в шаблон и от рисовать, но я не могу понять как мне в переменную засунуть шаблон, ведь он сразу же выбрасывается на страницу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через str_replace.

```
$tpl = <<<'EOF'
<?php
class %class_name% {

}
?>
EOF;

$class_name = "User";

$result  = str_replace('%class_name%',$class_name, $tpl);
```